# Computing a certain Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I am trying to answer this question: Suppose $p$ is an odd prime and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining a primitive $p$th root of 1 in $\mathbb{C}$. (a) Show that $K$ contains a unique quadratic extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}.$ (b) What is Gal$(K/F)$?

For part (a), I can let $\zeta_p$ be a primitive $p$th root of 1. Then $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p).$ I know that Gal$(K/\mathbb{Q})=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times},$ which is a cyclic group of order $p-1,$ which is even. Thus 2 divides $p-1$, and Gal$(K/\mathbb{Q})$ has a unique subgroup of order 2. By the Galois correspondence, this implies $K$ contains a unique quadratic extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.
(b) I am not sure how to go about finding Gal$(K/F).$

Comment: What does the Galois correspondence tell you?

Comment: It would have order (p-1)/2, right?

Comment: Yes, and it tells you exactly which group it is.

Comment: I don't follow how I know what the group is from its order.

Comment: The Galois correspondence itself tells you exactly which group it is. But also, a finite cyclic group has precisely one subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of its order.

Comment: The fact about the cyclic groups implies the Galois group is the cyclic group of order (p-1)/2, then? I still don’t understand what you mean by the galois correspondence telling me what the group is exactly. I only know there is a one-to-one correspondence between subgroups and intermediate fields.

Comment: Do you know *what* that one-to-one correspondence is? Also, the Galois group isn't *the* cyclic group of order $\tfrac{p-1}{2}$. It is *a* cyclic group of order $\tfrac{p-1}{2}$. It is worth making explicit what its elements are.

Comment: Aren’t they all isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed all isomorphic. But it is often useful/interesting/necessary to know more about a group than just its isomorphism type. Especially in Galois theory.  The question *'What is $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$'* leaves some room for interpretation of course, but I would give explicit generators and relations for the group.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you.

Comment: What Servaes is getting at with the Galois correspondence is, if $M/K$ is normal, and $L$ is an intermediate field normal over $K$, then there's a relation between the groups of $M/L$, $M/K$, and $L/K$.

Comment: Could you give a reference? As you can see, I clearly don’t know this, and hence keep asking.

Comment: It should be in every textbook that covers Galois Theory. See also the section, Properties of the correspondence, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory

Comment: So that would tell me cyclic group of order $p-1$ modded out by Gal($K/F$) is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$ This implies then that Gal($K/F$) is cyclic group of order $\frac{p-1}{2}.$ Is this correct?

Comment: As an abstract group, yes. But it's a concrete group and, as @Servaes says, you can give an explicit generator for the group.

Comment: So let Gal($K/\mathbb{Q})=<\sigma>$. Then Gal($K/F)=<\sigma^{2}>.$ Is this where you are pointing at?

Comment: That should do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your help: I am new to this and it was hard to wrap my mind around it.